# translate div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, translate-animation

I need to have a div move out on a click, and them move back in on a second event that it's binded to. Now, this works just fine, but only the first time. It needs to be able to occur over and over on multiple clicks.

The way to do this seems to be with `translate` but it's all on Css, which doesn't like click. (I've tried, and it's not working).Can anyone point me to a site that can explain how, or just help me out themselves? Thanksedit: okay, here's the script...

```
$('li, .thumbs').on('click', function() {
        $("#myVid").css("-webkit-transform","translate(-2070px, 0px)");
                //click plays a video
//some stuff happens
$('#myVid').bind("playing", function() {
        $("#myVid").css("-webkit-transform","translate(0px, 0px)");
```

that's really all that's actually relevant to the issue... 
**Edit: so, I changed it to CSS `addClass` and `removeClass`this is the current script

```
$('li, .thumbs').on('click', function() {
        $("#myVid").addClass('move');
//stuff happens
$('#myVid').bind("playing", function() {
        $("#myVid").removeClass('move');
```

and then the CSS

```
.move {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2000px);
}
```

but while it works, it blinks *alot*

Comment: Show us the relevant part of the code you have so far. :)

Comment: showing you html and css will help us the serve you better..

Comment: Have a peek at the js fiddle I posted.  I'd highly, highly recommend establishing a CSS rule to manage the `webkit-transform` states, rather than manually adding CSS to the attributes `style` attribute.  It will be much more maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just churned out this jsfiddle... hopefully it helps.

I like to add a CSS class to elements that need to be changed (or a parent element to trigger a whole set of changes).

In the example, by just adding & removing the "moved" class to my div, it will adjust the necessary space.

http://jsfiddle.net/fvgaK/5/

[Edit:  updated to make it ie-compatible]

Comment: The solution which you have provided does work in IE. It is not compatible with different browsers..

Comment: haha -- sorry. I work on mobile-only all day long, I forgot all about it.

Comment: ok, i just updated it to do a basic adjustment of the "left" property

Comment: better for others, but thats fine for me (its for ios5, soooo)

Comment: [Updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/fvgaK/1/), for everyone else.  Note, this comment may be useless if answer owner updates answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using CSS3. But It doesn't run on all browser.

You can take advantage of informations here.
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/

Also You can do this way.

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* safari and chrome */
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);/*firefox browsers */
    transform: rotate(30deg);/*other */
    -ms-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Internet Explorer 9 */
    -o-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJdxc/

EDIT:

I saw this javascript plugin while I was searching on internet. It is very useful for translate process.

http://fabricjs.com/

http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/

Answer (score 0):

To solve the blinking / janking thing that might be going on you can try setting the css property `backface-visibility`to `hidden` on the animated element(s).

In your case:

```
#myVid {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

this solved my issues with "blinking" elements.

more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility